# XtraGrid Cell Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using XtraGrid in my app. I want to group some cells togethere and replace them with group name. Following is the description.

[image]

I above image I have selected few cells from First columns. Now, from context menu when I will click on "Group", I will popup up a dialog for group name. Now here onwards the problem is.

1. I want to replace the cell containts logically with the group name. So in grid, for first column's selected cells, but while viweing it should appear as single cell. I have tried the cell merging feature of the xtragrid but that disbales the row selection feature. How to do this?
2. The grid shown above is bounded grid, so if I tried to do grouping for lets say Integer type of column, then how can I replace the group name which is string in integer column? is this possible in grid?
3. Can I add the unbounded column in bounded grid?

Please help.

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: I am not able to see the image that I uploded through a button on editor. Are you guys able to see it?

Answer (score 1):

The question is 4 years old, but for those who googled this and have the same questions, you could try this:

1. You are right: To show cells of the first column with same content as a single cell use merging: Set `Column1.OptionsColumn.AllowMerge` to true. You can influence the merging behaviour using the Views `CellMerge` Event. As you do not have a continouos row in case of a merged cell, you cannot use
   RowSelect.
2. To use Grouping you can call `Column1.Group()`. To specify the value wich is taken for comparison you can specify the `Column1.GroupInterval` to e.g. `Value` or `DisplayText`. The Cells DisplayText can be customized using the `CustomColumnDisplayText` event.
3. As far as I know it is not possible to add an unbound colmn to a
   BandedgridView. Why would you want to do this?

Generally there is a fast and qualified support at [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/) you can contact.